# What is the status of this strong form of Hedetniemi's conjecture?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

In this question, a **graph** is a finite, undirected graph without loops or multiple edges, and a **colouring** of a graph is a proper vertex colouring.  The **product** $G \times H$ of graphs $G$ and $H$ is the graph whose vertex-set is the product of the vertex-sets of $G$ and $H$ and whose edge-set is the product of the edge-sets of $G$ and $H$, with the obvious incidence relation.

Let $G$ and $H$ be graphs.  Any $n$-colouring of $G$ gives rise to an $n$-colouring of $G \times H$: just paint $(x, y)$ the same colour as $x$.  (Or, if you prefer, an $n$-colouring of a graph is just a homomorphism into the complete graph $K_n$, so we can compose the colouring $G \to K_n$ with the projection $G \times H \to G$ to obtain a colouring $G \times H \to K_n$.)  Similarly, any $n$-colouring of $H$ gives rise to an $n$-colouring of $G \times H$.  Let us say that a colouring of $G \times H$ arising in one of these two ways is **obtained by projection**.

The previous paragraph makes it clear that $\chi(G \times H) \leq \min\{ \chi(G), \chi(H) \}$, where $\chi$ means chromatic number.  [Hedetniemi's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedetniemi_conjecture) states that this is an equality. In other words, it says that there are no colourings of a product more economical than those obtained by projection.  My question:

> Let $G$ and $H$ be graphs.  Is every colouring of $G \times H$ with $\chi(G \times H)$ colours obtained by projection?

The answer can't be known to be yes, unless I've missed some news, since that would imply Hedetniemi's conjecture.  But perhaps the answer is no, or perhaps it's known that this apparently stronger conjecture would actually be implied by Hedetniemi's original conjecture.

---

**Edit**  Assume the graphs are connected, otherwise the answer is trivially no.  (E.g. consider $(K_2 \sqcup K_2) \times K_2$.)

Comment: Dear Tom, as far as I know it is wide open.

Comment: @Gil: thanks.  Is this strong form something that's been discussed much in the literature?

Comment: Tom, ahh I missed your strong version. I suppose by minimal coloring you mean a coloring with minimum number of colors, right? I find your strong version hard to believe.

Comment: Did you check the product of two odd cycles?

Comment: @GilKalai, you're quite right, that's exactly the thing to do.  There's a colouring of $C_3 \times C_5$ that shows that the answer is no.  I'll write it up into a community wiki answer in a minute.  (And yes, by "minimal colouring" I meant what you said.)

Comment: What I've been wondering about for quite some time now is: what would be some high-level reasons that tell why the Hedetniemi conjecture is so hard? I'm not familiar with the literature, so would be really happy if you (or anyone else) could shed some light. Thanks!

Comment: Suvrit, I have no idea - I'm a total amateur at this.  Maybe Gil can say.  What puzzles me is why Hedetniemi's conjecture isn't *much* more famous.  For instance, it seems to me a more fundamental conjecture than the 4-colour conjecture (now theorem), since it doesn't involve the concept of planarity.  I suppose that's partly because you can't interpret it in terms of colouring a map of the world.  Still, though, it's a huge thing not to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no.  In the comments, Gil Kalai suggested looking at products of two odd cycles, and indeed, this yields a counterexample.

Consider $C_3 \times C_5$, where $C_n$ denotes the $n$-cycle.  This has chromatic number $3$, and there is a 3-colouring given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&1&2&3\\
1&2&1&2&3\\
1&2&1&2&3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(in what I hope is obvious notation).  This is plainly not obtained by projection.

In fact, this is also a counterexample to a weaker form of this strong form of Hedetniemi's conjecture: that every colouring of $G \times H$ by $\chi(G \times H)$ colours is obtained by projection *after some automorphism of $G \times H$*.  For any such colouring of $C_3 \times C_5$ has *either* 5 of each colour *or* 3 of one and 6 of each of the other two; but neither is the case for the colouring shown above.

Comment: Very nice! Still, I tend to agree with Tardif who wrote in his "40 years later" survey, that Hedetniemi's conjecture is saying that lifted colorings are *essentially* the best way to color the product. But what do we really mean by "best" :)?